# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method' ошибка на строке 152

Tags: python, python-3.x, разработка-игр

Делаю карточную игру и сделал проверку, если Манекен.values <= Карта.values:
то манекен побеждён но пишет ошибку
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'builtin_function_or_method' and 'builtin_function_or_method'
Помогите её решить, ошибку никак найти не могу и как её решить тоже пожалуйста помогите её решить
a = int(input("Хотите начать сражение? против манекен 1-да 2- нет"))
if a == 1:
print(ССГР)
pov = input("Напишите какой герой вам нужен")

```
        if pov == "Вертолёт":
            Карта["Вертолёт"] = "урон 50"


        if pov == "Спартанец":
            Карта["Спартанец"] = "урон 50"

        if pov == "Тяжёлый Боец":
            Карта["Тяжёлый Боец"] = "урон 50"

        if pov == "Медик":
            Карта["Медик"] = "урон 0"

        if Манекен.values <= Карта.values:
            print("Манекен побеждён")
            Манекен["Манекен"] = 'побеждён'
            print(Манекен)

        if Манекен.values >= Карта.values:
            print("Манекен вас выиграл :|")
```

Comment: В ошибке указана её причина и строка, где она возникает. Смотри в ту строку и подумай, что ты там хочешь сделать.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Так ладно. Даже напишу для справки if Манекен.values < Карта.values: если значение словаря Манекен меньше чем значение словаря Карта то мы пишем что манекен побеждён и его значение обнуляется подумал, но не понял похоже я тупой кайф:)

Comment: если мы сделаем Манекен['values'] < Карта['values' то нам будут нужны переменные в которых они будут хранится, такое в принципе можно попробовать

Comment: Ты понимаешь, что такое ``Манекен.values``? Это **не** число!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас что хранится в `Манекен.values` и `Карта.values`? Явно там что-то, что нельза так сравнивать. Выведите на печать и посмотрите!

Если это словари, то видимо надо `Манекен['values'] < Карта['values']`? Или `Манекен.values()`?

Comment: Я, конечно, понимаю, что репы не хватает на комменты, но, боюсь, если вы и дальше будете писать такие "ответы", репы у вас скоро совсем не останется.

Comment: HerrAskin спасибо вам большое, я посмотрел и действительно были вещи которые нельзя сравнивать. Спасибо вам!

Comment: Судя по ошибке там функции, которые нужно вызывать (со скобками)